# Node JS react Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Hello' before initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

Get "Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Hello' before initialization" error in a simple component class, and cannot figure out why, please advise.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styled, {css} from 'react-emotion';

const StyledDiv = styled('div')`
  color: red;
`;

export default class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <div>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

the error is gone if I remove

```
 const StyledDiv = styled('div')`
  color: red;
`;
```

Comment: You're referencing `Hello` someplace in your code before it's initialized.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule what you mentioned is the logic, but not sure where it happens. The hello component is the only component in the app so far. And the error occurs when using "styled"(may styled decorates the hello component before it is initialized, but I am not sure)

Comment: We don't know where it happens either, because you haven't produced the code to make the error reproducible.